# How do I use include method with the whole alphabet?

Tags: ruby

I want to know if a string includes the form `'+#someletter#+'`, where `#someletter#` is a 
letter. If the string is `'dogs+d+'`, it would be `true` because it contains `'+d+'`. If the string is `'dogs++c'`, it would be `false` because the `'c'` wasn't surrounded by `'+'` signs.

I was thinking it was something using regexp like

```
string.include? '+/a-z/+'
```

but that doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include?` does not accept a regex. To use a regex, you need a different method.

```
string =~ /\+[a-z]\+/
```

Comment: this worked great, incidentally, what does the =~ mean? sorry im pretty new to computer programming and ruby.

Comment: Andrew, see the doc for the method [Regexp@=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E).